# Solving an Integral using Cauchy's integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have got a question about the calculation of two specific integrals:
\begin{align*}
&\int_C z^n e^z \, dz \quad n\in\mathbb{N}_0 \\
&\int_{\vert z \vert = 1}  z^{-n} e^z \, dz \quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
Where $C$ is the line from $0$ to $2 \pi i$ and $\vert z \vert = 1$ is the circle with radius $1$.
Hint is to use cauchy's integral theorem. At this moment I tried solving the integrals using the line integrals but this leads to a lot of calculations which seem to be unsatisfying. Do you have an idea or parametrization for $C$ or $\vert z \vert =1$ which does 'work well'? Furthermore I am not quite sure whether we can use the CIT for the second integral because $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ is no star-domain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you studied the residue theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first integral just use $z=iy$,

$$ A_n = \int_C z^n e^z dz= \int_0^{2\pi} (iy)^n e^{iy} idy $$

$$= \int_0^{2\pi} (iy)^{n+1} e^{iy}  dy $$

$$= (i)^{n+1}\int_0^{2\pi} y^n e^{iy}  dy $$

This last integral can be obtained by using differentiation under the integral sign on,

$$ I(\alpha) = i\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\alpha y}dy = i\frac{1}{i\alpha} \left( e^{2\pi i \alpha} - 1 \right),$$

Where

$$A_n = i\left(\frac{d}{d\alpha}\right)^n I(\alpha) \mid_{\alpha =1} $$

---

For the second integral over $\vert z \vert =1 $ we can use Cauchy's integral theorem in its generic form,

$$ \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dx = \frac{ 2\pi i}{n!} f^{(n)}(z_0), $$

Since the derivative of $e^z$ is itself and $z_0=0$ we can easily compute $\int_C z^{-n} e^z dz=2\pi i / (n-1)!$.

Comment: I honestly do not follow you in $I(\alpha)$. Where is $y^n$ gone?

Comment: The $y^n$ aren't in $I$ but they are in its derivitaves. Try taking one derivative with respect to $\alpha$ of the integrand and see what happens.

Comment: This method is often called "differentiation under the integral sign" in casse you want to look it up.

Comment: The second one is a pretty standard application of the integral formula. What set does $\bar{U_r}(0)$ represent?

Comment: Please note what the OP said: *"I tried solving the integrals using the line integrals but this leads to a lot of calculations which seem to be unsatisfying."* Have you really tried to compute the $n$-th derivative? Just try and you'll understand!

Comment: $\overline U_r (0)$ is probably the closed disk of center $0$ and radius $1$.

Comment: A short question: as I see it the second integral evalutes to $\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}$?

Comment: @Abbraxas, Yes you are right. I'll fix it.

Comment: In order to compute the $n$-th derivative of $I$ (after integration), one might use Leibniz's formula: $(fg) ^{(n)} = \sum \limits _{k=0} ^n f^{(k)} g^{(n-k)}$, with $f= \frac 1 \alpha$ and $g=\Bbb e ^{2 \pi \Bbb i \alpha} -1$. One gets $f^{(k)}=\frac {(-1)^k k!} {\alpha ^{k+1}}$ and $g^{(n-k)}=(2 \pi \Bbb i) ^{n-k} \Bbb e ^{2 \pi \Bbb i \alpha}$ if $k<n$. In the end, one evaluates $I^{(n)} (\alpha)$ in $\alpha=1$. The method of deriving under the integral is smart, but in the end the volume of calculations is approximately the same as in integrating by parts and using recursion on $n$.